# Abelianization of Group--Equal Elements are Conjugates?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $\phi$ is the abelianization of some $G$. Moreover, suppose that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ for some $x,y \in G$. Is it true that this occurs if and only if $y = gxg^{-1}$ for some $g \in G$?

The one direction is trivial: if $y = gxg^{-1}$, then $\phi (y) = \phi(gxg^{-1}) = \phi(g)\phi(x)\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(x)$. But what about the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what is true is that $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \iff xG'=yG'$. That is, $x$ and $y$ are representatives of the same coset of $G'$. So this is true iff $y^ {-1}x$ is a product of commutators.If for example $y=gxg^ {-1}$, then $y^ {-1}x=[g^ {-1},x]$. Hence conjugacy classes collapse to a singleton under $\phi$.

Comment: You mean $[g,x^{-1}]$?

Comment: With me $[a,b]:=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, maybe unlike your definition.

Comment: Yeah, I use $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

This equivalence only holds if $\phi$ is injective, in which case it's trivial. For if $\phi$ is not injective, then there is some $x\neq 1$ with $\phi(x)=\phi(1)=1$, and $x$ is not conjugate to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G = S_5$, then $\phi:S_5 \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ is the sign homomorphism.
We have $\phi(\operatorname{id})$ = 1 = $\phi( (1,2) (3,4) )$, but obiviously $\operatorname{id}$ and $(1,2)(3,4)$ are not conjugates.

Comment: I think $\phi$ is meant to be the homomorphism from $G$ to its abelianization; $\phi : G \to G/[G,G]$ (or $G/G'$ if you like).

Comment: @pjs36 Actually this works, because $[S_5,S_5]=A_5$ (though it is not exactly obvious).

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Whoops!